# Npx (node?) error on libstdc++.so.6 taken from "snap" folder

Tags: snap, libraries, nodejs

I have an error launching npx which refers to libstdc++.so.6 library:

```
/snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1)
Failed to load module: /home/nik/snap/code/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
```

I am asking here because I noticed that I do have another version of the libstdc++.so.6 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Why is npx (node) referring to the "snap" folder?
What is the scope of this folder?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was launching the command from the VS Code terminal (vscode was installed from snap).
Launching the same command from a "natural" bash does not issue the problem...